# Joi - Required based on value on other key

Tags: node.js, joi

I want to validate an input which only has two fields(namely text and image). Both **text** and **image** are string and one of them must always be present. When one of the fields is absent then the other one can not be an empty string.
this is the Validation I have defined.

```
text: Joi.string()
    .when('image',
        {
            is: Joi.string(),
            then: Joi.string().allow(''),
            otherwise: Joi.string().required(),
        }
    ),
image: Joi.string().allow(null),
```

when I use the below input, the validation allows the data to pass. I dont how to change the validation to prohibit the below input.

```
post: {
    text: ''
}
```

Comment: @James I used 'exist()' and it worked. Please post your comment as an answer so that I can mark your answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `exist()` instead of `string()` when validating:

```
when('image', {
  is: Joi.exist(),
  then: Joi.string().allow(''),
  otherwise: Joi.string().required(),
})
```

Answer (score 1):

```
body:Joi.object({
    notifiyto:Joi.string().valid('selectedCustomer','selectedDrivers','allCustomers','allDrivers').required(),
    notifiyIds:Joi.when('notifiyto',{
      is: Joi.exist().valid('selectedCustomer', 'selectedDrivers'),
      then: Joi.required(),
    }),
    message:Joi.string()
  })
```